# Treat hyphens as part of a word?

Tags: syntax-table, words

I use:

```el
(global-superword-mode t)
```

in my `init.el` because I don't want Emacs to treat `_` as a word delimiter.

How do I do the same thing for `-`? I'd like to enable this globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `(global-superword-mode t)`

[Note that mode functions are not documented as accepting `t` as argument - you should enable modes either as `(mode)` or with a non-zero natural number such as `(mode 1)`.]

> How do I do the same thing for `-`?

That depends on the syntax table (see [`(info "(elisp) Syntax Tables")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Tables.html)), and thus the modes, in use.  AFAICT, `superword-mode` delegates all of its boundary finding to the command `forward-symbol`.  So if `forward-symbol` recognises `-` as constituting a symbol, then so will `superword-mode`.

In Elisp, `-` already has `symbol` syntax (see `C-u C-x =`, `C-h s`) so `forward-symbol` will skip all of e.g. `global-superword-mode` in one go.  This is also the case in e.g. `fundamental-mode` and `text-mode`.

For changing the syntax category of `-`, there's the command `modify-syntax-entry`; see [`(info "(elisp) Syntax Table Functions")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Table-Functions.html).  For example, you could do `M-x modify-syntax-entry RET - _ RET` to give it `symbol` syntax in the current buffer.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything I can add to `init.el` to have this set automatically?

Comment: @WickedJargon Depends on where you would want such a setting to take effect - which modes, buffers, etc. Once you have identified these, then you can add the corresponding calls to `(modify-syntax-entry ...)` to the corresponding mode hooks or `with-eval-after-load` stanzas.

Comment: How do I enable it globally?

Comment: @WickedJargon Maybe you could add the call to `(modify-syntax-entry ..)` on `after-change-major-mode-hook`, so that it runs in every mode.